# Is my proof to : A ∪ ( B ∩ C ) = ( A ∪ B ) ∩ ( A ∪ C ) correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The problem asks to show that : A ∪ ( B ∩ C )  = ( A ∪ B ) ∩ ( A ∪ C )
My attempt is :

Let's assume that x ∈ ( B ∩ C )

Therefore, x ∈ B and x ∈ C

Also x ∈ A ∪ ( B ∩ C )

Hence, x ∈ ( A ∪ B )

x ∈ ( A ∪ C )

Therefore, x ∈ ( A ∪ B ) ∩ ( A ∪ C )

This implies that,  A ∪ ( B ∩ C ) ⊂ ( A ∪ B ) ∩ ( A ∪ C )

And similarly it can be shown that, ( A ∪ B ) ∩ ( A ∪ C ) ⊂ A ∪ ( B ∩ C )

Therefore, A ∪ ( B ∩ C ) = ( A ∪ B ) ∩ ( A ∪ C )

Could anyone verify if this is correct? the solution provided in my textbook has gone with a different approach.

Comment: "This implies that, A ∪ ( B ∩ C ) ⊂ ( A ∪ B ) ∩ ( A ∪ C )"  No.  This implies $B\cap C \subset (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$.  You assumed that $x \in B\cap C\subset A \cup (B\cap C)$.  That is a  *specific* not a general $x \in A\cup(B\cap C)$.  To prove $A\cup (B\cap C) \subset ....$ you must assume $x \in A \cup (B\cap C)$ and *not* assume anything more.  By assuming $x \in B \cap C$ you assumed too much.

Comment: This is a bit like proving $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Z$ by assuming $n\in \mathbb N$ then $n \in \mathbb N \cup \mathbb Q = \mathbb Q$.  But $n \in \mathbb N \cup \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z$.  So $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Z$.  You should $n \in \mathbb Q \implies n\in \mathbb Q$ !!!*if*!!!! $n$ is an integer.  You haven't shown that $n \in \mathbb Q\implies n \in \mathbb Q$ if $n$ is *NOT* an integer..... So what if $x \not \in B\cap C$ but $x \in A\cup (B\cap C)$?  You haven't shown how that would imply $x \in (A\cup B)\cap (A \cup C)$.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly correct; but you did not check the other case $x\in A$.